# How to return multiple values VIEW in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, return-value

I was trying to change `ImageView` in one Fragment from another Fragment. But since this cannot be done without container, I have to create another `view` value with the `inflater` method. Then I need to return these view values with the inflater methods. How do I return two views?

code is written in a fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstfragment, container, false)
        val view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondfragment, container, false)

        val imgPF: ImageView = view2.findViewById(R.id.imageView)

        imgPF.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_29)

        view.ButtonFromFirstFragment.setOnClickListener{
            //Unimportant code
        }

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return view //Approximately here i need to return two views, but how? 
                    //And can it be done somehow differently?
    }
```

Comment: You create a layout that have the 2 layouts inside, and then inflate one layout instead of inflating two different layouts. You can do this by using `include` in the new layout or by using the views of the other 2 layouts inside your new layout.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should not have 2 fragments within a fragment. Please double check that you are not confusing fragments with views.

If you want to have those 2 fragments in an activity and you are showing both of your fragments at the same time then you should have 2 separate fragments:

Fragment A:

(...)

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstfragment, container, false)

        view.ButtonFromFirstFragment.setOnClickListener{
            //Unimportant code
        }

        return view
    }
```

(...)

Fragment B:
(...)

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondfragment, container, false)

        val imgPF: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)

        imgPF.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_29)
    
        return view 
    }
```

Comment: No, I forgot to add that this first fragment is actually manipulative. It sounds silly, but it is. There is no other fragment where I can change the item from layout that is not bound to any fragment. SecondFragment is just a layout file. I apologize for my mistake.